# NodeRed application wont start - Script exited with status 2

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

Does anyone know what this means?

```
3/31/2016 5:21:20 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid da2ece80-8938-4d58-a0f5-0ddc96326d43 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
3/31/2016 5:21:22 PM    OUT DEA Got staging request for app with id da2ece80-8938-4d58-a0f5-0ddc96326d43
3/31/2016 5:21:33 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid da2ece80-8938-4d58-a0f5-0ddc96326d43 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
3/31/2016 5:21:33 PM    OUT STG -----> Downloaded app package (116K)
3/31/2016 5:21:33 PM    ERR API encountered error: Staging error: failed to stage application:
3/31/2016 5:21:33 PM    ERR API Script exited with status 2
```

Comment: That appears to be a platform error... hopefully a temporary condition.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the cached binaries were out of sync. The BlueMix devops team fixed it very quickly.